# Is there a user and access control library for MERN stack?

Tags: users, node-js, permissions, access-control, react-js

I am currently learning the MERN stack, having previously worked mostly in Django. However, I find myself recoding the same things over and over again manually and not being entirely satisfied with the end product, such as programming a user database, roles, and permissions. In Django, this is all done automatically, which I loved. Is there a library I can simply install in NodeJS that acts more or less the same way? Should this be handled on the backend in NodeJS or Express, or in the frontend with React? What are the best practices for this?

The library should be able to do the following:
create and modify users
assign roles to users
assign permissions to roles

Comment: [Recommendations](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic for this site, as well as for most Stack Exchange sites - as commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962770/is-there-a-user-and-access-control-library-for-mern-stack) over at Stack Overflow.